# Why did my peltier modules stay warm inside vacuum?

Tags: thermodynamics, vacuum, thermal-conductivity, thermoelectricity

My problem is a bit more complex, but I will do my best to describe it. I have assembled the following setup:

[image]

**I want to acheve the lowest possible temperature in vacuum on top of my stacked Peltier modules** (one on top of another, connected in series).

In order to achieve this, I have placed them inside a steel TVAC chamber. Directly underneath the modules on the other side is a radiator with a fan to help dissipate the heat that the modules will generate on the bottom of the TVAC. The temperature on top of the Peltiers I measure with a thermocouple hooked up to a multimeter. Peltiers are powered by a lab power supply outside of the climatic chamber. I also applied thermal paste very generously between Peltiers and where they touch the floor of the TVAC, as well as between the radiator and TVAC (**and dipped the thermocouple in thermal paste before taping it to the Peltiers**).

The plan was as follows:

1. Drain air from the vacuum chamber;
2. Cool down the climatic chamber to -40 degrees Celsius (its lowest possible temp);
3. Power on the Peltiers, slowly lowering the temperature even lower, to around -50 Celsius on the measured side.
4. Success!

But here's what happened instead:

1. Drained air from the vacuum chamber;
2. Cooled down the climatic chamber to -40 degrees Celsius (as confirmed by a trusted thermometer);
3. Peltiers temp (powered off!) showed ~3 degrees Celsius at lowest at the beginning, and then it somehow came back to room temp (22 deg Celsius);
4. Powered on Peltiers, temp reading dropped as expected, but only to 0 degrees at most (couldn't really expect more starting from +22)

**My biggest concern here is: why did Peltiers got warm again by themselves (unpowered!) and stayed warm and didn't want to cool down by the ambient temperature?** They were in vacuum, yes, but they were touching the TVAC floor (thermal paste included), and the TVAC was in a very low temperature; therefore i would expect the Peltier modules to cool down as well, but they did not. Why is that?

Is it maybe because I should have powered them from the start, and not after cooling down the climatic chamber? Or maybe I should have first cooled down the climatic chamber AND THEN drained the TVAC from air?

Sorry if this may seem a silly question, but I am getting quite confused by this behavior and I might be missing an obvious answer.

Comment: How good is the insulation along the Peltier devices' power cables? How good is their contact to the edge of the vacuum chamber? How good is the thermal conductivity of the vacuum chamber?

Comment: Their contact to the vacuum chamber walls is good - they are taped to it with thermal paste between them and the chamber floor.

But as for the insulation along the cables and the thermal conductivity of the vacuum chamber, it's hard for me to say. I did test the peltiers inside vacuum outside of the climatic chamber and the other side of the vacuum chamber got hot, so I would assume the thermal conductivity is good (that was back when I didn't use a radiator nor a fan).

Comment: what if you unplug the peltiers and stuff all the wiring inside the vacuum chamber (except for one thermometer) and then draw the vacuum and check the temperature of the peltiers? Still 22 degrees? If that solves it then the heat must have gotten in through the wiring.

Comment: Steel is ~50x less thermally conductive than aluminum, as one data point.

Comment: Well, now that you have mentioned it, it is not impossible that the wires going outside have leaked heat into the TVAC chamber, and maybe even to the thermocouple itself. I will need to conduct additional experiments to confirm or discard this theory.